# Controlar propiedad objeto js si se redimensiona la pantalla

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

estoy utilizando una librería para crear un slider de imágenes, y me gustaría poder modificar la propiedad del objeto que se crea cuando el usuario redimensiona la pantalla o por defecto es pequeña.
Por ejemplo, este pequeño fragmento funciona muy bien cuando la resolución de partida es de ese tamaño o superior, ajustando el valor de la propiedad perPage.

```
<script>
    new Splide('#splide', {
            type: 'loop',
            perPage: screen.width < 1000 ? 1 : 2,

            height: '39rem',
            cover: true,
            breakpoins: {
                640: {
                    height: '6rem',
                    display: 'none',
                }
            }
        }

    ).mount()
</script>
```

La pregunta es como podría controlar esta propiedad si cambia el redimensionamiento de la pantalla o si es pequeña, es algo parecido a hacerlo responsive.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado=> dentro de los breakpoints se pueden pone la propiedad per page. Esta es una forma más sencilla de controlar el diseño responsive.